# This script is deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start - yard.sh

Tags: hadoop

When I am trying to run my hadoop cluster via command "start-all.sh" this following error will arising ...
"This script is deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start - yard.sh"
Please help me to solve it, thank you so much,

Comment: So use `start-dfs.sh` and `start-yard.sh` instead; what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Deprecation means it should be avoided, typically because it is being **superseded**. The term is also sometimes used for a feature, design, or practice that is ***permitted but no longer recommended***. And this message is not at all a problem, its just a warning.So follow whatever suggested instead of Deprecation

Answer (score 0):

It means your command is righr but old. It will run but if you use instead given command then it wolud be great.